# how to insert values to Access through SQL and ADODB object when the table has an autoincrement field?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

i got a question when insert values to Access through SQL statements and ADODB object.
this is my Access table "test"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yndcN.png)

the primary field "tid" is an autoincrement field,when i insert new values by SQL statements

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO test VALUES('john')"

adoConn.Execute CommandText:=strSQL
```

i got an exception that i have to write my statement like this

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO test VALUES(1, 'john')"
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Which line is the error and what is the error

Comment: Please share the error log.

Comment: does `"INSERT INTO test(uname) VALUES('john')"` work?

Comment: Sorry i'm using excel chinese version,so the error message is chinese.it mainly said that the field "tid" is need.so i need to write the statement like this:strSQL = "INSERT INTO test VALUES(1, 'john')"

Comment: this statement works.what if there are many columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, if tid is auto increment:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO test (uname) VALUES ('john')";
```

Comment: yes it works,thanks so much.but what if there are many columns?my table have 20 more fields,i think that's not so convenience to write them down all.